# Get all Brand Accounts Via google API

Tags: google-api

I see all the brand accounts belonging to my account at  myaccount.google.com/brandaccounts. I've looked at several APIs and cannot see a way to query these. Does anybody know if there is an API to get all brand accounts for an account?

Comment: From my research also there doesn't seem to be any public APIs to get the brand accounts.

Comment: Thanks SUB0DH, that is what I concluded too. Page scraping here we come.... :)